# How to customize Polylang Language switcher dropdown wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, switch-statement, dropdown, multilingual, polylang

I am using Zerif lite theme in my wordpress website I have placed language switcher dropdown next to my navbar on the homepage . I have 3 languages .
I am facing two issues currently :

1. After logging in in my Wordpress admin the language switcher is working , I am able to change language by clicking on the dropdown but after logging out,  I opened my website in two browser's(chrome,safari) the dropdown doesn't seem to work . Language is not changing ???

2.How to customize the language switcher dropdown color,size,font,border etc ?

Please help !!!Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to deactivate other plugins maybe it is caused by one of them.
2. You can customize in CSS, in wordpress or by some text editor in your child theme.